# Regex to stop at a certain space in this fix message

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match the string `Please Trade this for me!` from the following text:

`8=FIX.4.2 9=0302 35=D 49=THING_PLACE 56=NOUN_NOUN 34=6004 52=20151110-18:56:56 115=REDACTED::::::::::CENSORED 1=TestAccount 18320=19731199105 207=N 38=10000 40=2 11=Order5931 109=NORTH 47=A 44=117 15=USD 48=DIS.N 21=1 55=DIS 54=1 18315=EXT 59=0 58=Please Trade this for me! 14010=NORTH_AMERICA 60=20151110-18:56:55.214 10=250`

I've tried using this regex without success: `/[a-zA-Z0-9\=.\s\:\-\_\/!]*(\s58=[a-zA-Z0-9\=.\:\-\_\/!]*\s)[a-zA-Z0-9\=.\s\:\-\_\/!]*/`

You can see it [here](https://regex101.com/r/fU9fY1/2). As you can see it ends up selecting far more than the desired text. Furthermore, it does the same if you select a different numeral value in place of 58.

Keep in mind there may not be punctuation at the end

Comment: Please add you information in the question.  Using outside links is nice for adding supplementary information or examples, but they good go away, rendering the question unusable for future readers.  It also makes it hard to understand you question on first read, having to skip back and forth between multiple browsers tabs. REad how to on asking good questions here - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  RIght now you links tell us nothing of the "logic" you are trying to replicate in your regex.

Comment: The other thing I would ask is whether this is really a regex problem.  It looks like the string you are searching in may have structured format (space-separated values) which may mean there a better ways to approach this problem. It is hard to say though without understanding what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @MikeBrant Yes this is definitely a regex problem. Another user has solved the issue for me. Regex101 is a good site to visualize exactly what Im doing without explaining it in words and avoiding redundancy in the post. Regardless, in the future ill post it both places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/pJ5wP1/3) (I'm assuming you're using a regex variant that supports zero length lookahead and lookbehind):

```
(?<=58\=).*?(?=\s*\d+\=)
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=58\=)` This is a zero width positive lookbehind that will match the boundary at the end of `58=`
- `.*?` This is minimally match any character.
- `(?=\s*\d+\=)` This is a zero width positive lookahead that will match the boundary at the beginning of `14010=`. The internal expression matches zero or more spaces (`\s*`) followed by one or more digits (`\d+`) and an equal sign (`\=`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\d{2,}\=([A-Za-z\s+!]{20,})\s+
```

https://regex101.com/r/fU9fY1/4